# How can I Combine or paste text in a linux command in terminal?

Tags: command-line

How can  I combine or paste text in a linux command in terminal?

I would like to execute the following linux command `ls -d $PWD/*`
which results: eg.

```
/media/elias/2000_0101_004828_006.MP4
/media/elias/2000_0101_011328_007.MP4
/media/elias/2000_0101_013829_008.MP4
/media/elias/2000_0101_020328_009.MP4
/media/elias/2000_0101_021020_006.MP4
/media/elias/2000_0101_021620_006.MP4
```

I would like to execute a linux command in a way that the produced printed result will be:

```
file '/media/elias/2000_0101_004828_006.MP4'
file '/media/elias/2000_0101_011328_007.MP4'
file '/media/elias/2000_0101_013829_008.MP4'
file '/media/elias/2000_0101_020328_009.MP4'
file '/media/elias/2000_0101_021020_006.MP4'
file '/media/elias/2000_0101_021620_006.MP4'
```

This is needed for the Videofiles.txt that ffmpeg concat command requires in order to manipulate videofiles. I would like to execute a single command line to do all this work automatically. The linux command results will be saved in a txt file e.g.

```
   ls -d $PWD/* > videofiles.txt
```

is that possible?

ps. my ls command lists files in date order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order isn't determined by `ls`, it depends on the lexical sort order `LC_COLLATE` applied to the shell `*` glob for your locale.

That said, I would avoid `ls` altogether and do something like

```
printf "file '%s'\n" $PWD/* > videofiles.txt
```

(you could change `*` to `*.MP4` if you want to match `.MP4` files only).

---

If you want the files to be ordered by modification time (aka "mtime") as you would get with `ls -t`, then that's not possible natively in bash, but is in zsh using *glob qualifiers* ex.

```
printf "file '%s'\n" $PWD/*.MP4(om)
```

to sort by mtime ascending (like `ls -t`) or

```
printf "file '%s'\n" $PWD/*.MP4(Om)
```

to sort by mtime descending (like `ls -tr`).

Comment: So, this command list files in chronological order? I found out that the command 'ls -d $PWD/* -ltr' list files in chronological order based on modified date. Is that wrong? "Type the ls -t command to list files or directories and sort by last modified date and time in descending order (biggest to smallest)."

Comment: @Estatistics `*` will expand in *lexical* order - if you want `*` to expand in file modification time (aka "mtime") order the same as `ls -t` that's hard to do in bash but easy in `zsh` for example

Comment: Then can you provide an example for zsh command with the same requirements with mtime order (oldest date in 1st file, newest date in the final file).

Comment: @Estatistics please see updated answer